# How to start a method multiple times, with different variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, google-chrome, task

I've been creating a autocheckout bot, and I'm very new to C#, and coding in general. I've gotten pretty far, almost done with the program, or so I thought, and now I want to have the ability to create multiple tasks, or run the task method multiple times. I also want to be able to input a different "profile", which has defined strings, such as login email, password, ect., on each task seperately. I'm very stuck and I have no idea where to even begin, maybe if someone could point me in the right direction for me to get started? last time I got some amazing help from this community, and it helped me a lot. Here is my current attempt:

```
  public void KeywordTask1()
    {
        Start();
        LogIn();
        FindProductByKeyword();
        stopwatch.Start();
        AddToCart();
        Checkout();
        TimeSpan CheckoutTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }
    public void KeywordTask2()
    {
        Start();
        LogIn();
        FindProductByKeyword();
        stopwatch.Start();
        AddToCart();
        Checkout();
        TimeSpan CheckoutTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }
```

I have buttons that start those tasks, but I also want the varibles to change, like a status text that I have set in my windows form. here is my GUI if it helps you understand my code a bit better:
https://gyazo.com/c6e9334e04aeb223e0afade6da8bec4e

Please let me know if you need anything else from me! I'm not sure if this is allowed but I'm willing to pay for someone to help me through this, not very much because I'm only 16 haha, but anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this is what you want but if you want to run method with different variable value then create method:

```
public void MyMethod(string myVariable)
{
//do something with myVariable
}
```

And you can pass different variable value when calling method:

```
MyMethod("123abc");
```

or something like:

```
var newVariable="123abc"
MyMethod(newVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

To start method with different input create method with variable

```
public void MyUsername(string username)
{
    MessageBox.Show(username);
}

private void buttonUsername1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUsername("Adam");
}
private void buttonUsername2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUsername("Jack");
}
```

To start method multiple time use loop

```
private void btnDoAllTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    // run 5 times
    while(count < 5)
    {
        count++;
        MyUsername("username" + count.ToString());
    }
}
```

or loop through array

```
private void btnDoAllTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listUsername = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    foreach (var username in listUsername)
    {
        MyUsername(username);
    }
}
```